# Regarding Guest user access to create record

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

I am using LWR template on which, i have created one LWC Component which i have created to make it available for guest user. It is a note making app.

**Access for Guest user as below :**
sObject included -
My_Note__c : read, create access

fields on My_Note__c
Name : read, edit
Note_Description__c : read edit

I am creating the note when guest user click create note as shown in below image -
 [image]

When I am using createRecord LDS function for creating record as guest user, I am getting **Unauthorized Access** as response. But, when **using apex class without sharing**, Guest user is able to create the record.

**Can anyone help why createRecord function is giving unauthorized access despite giving all necessary permission?**

Comment: Take a look at the [guest user security policies and timelines](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5) for some detail around how Salesforce are putting the squeeze on use of guest access. They are removing more and more capabilities in the context of the guest user. You may need to reconsider what you are trying to do here. Also read the basic docs for [guest user access to create records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_give_guest_users_access_to_create_records.htm).

Comment: I will consider your point. Thanks!